# Using sendFlush and sendChunkBS in forkIO

Tags: haskell, concurrency, yesod, conduit

I'm developing a Yesod application and I'm encountering an error while trying to use [`sendFlush`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-core-1.4.24/docs/Yesod-Core-Handler.html#v:sendFlush) and [`sendChunkBS`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-core-1.4.24/docs/Yesod-Core-Handler.html#v:sendFlush) inside a [`forkIO`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/threads-0.5.1.4/docs/Control-Concurrent-Thread.html#v:forkIO).

`sendFlush` and `sendChunkBS` are of type `Monad m => Producer m (Flush Builder)` but `forkIO` requires an `IO ()`.

Here is the code:

```
respondSource "" $ do
  sendFlush

  (rid, rwait) <- liftIO $ T.forkIO $
    do
      let loop = do
            output <- liftIO $ SB.recv targetSocket (2^11)
            liftIO $ putStrLn $ "SB.recv: " ++ BSC.unpack output

            when (not $ BS.null output) $
              do
                sendChunkBS output
                sendFlush
                loop
      loop
```

and the error:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘IO a0’
            with actual type ‘C.ConduitM
                                i0 (C.Flush Data.ByteString.Builder.Internal.Builder) m0 ()’
Relevant bindings include
  loop :: C.ConduitM
            i0 (C.Flush Data.ByteString.Builder.Internal.Builder) m0 ()
    (bound at app/Main.hs:96:13)
In a stmt of a 'do' block: loop
In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
  ‘do { let loop = ...;
        loop }’
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try adding a call to [`runConduit`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.2.7/docs/Data-Conduit.html#v:runConduit) just before `forkIO`;

```
  (rid, rwait) <- liftIO $ T.forkIO $ runConduit $
```

Your argument to forkIO is a ConduitM action, and `runConduit`
will convert that to an IO action.

Comment: `runConduit` doesn't work because it requires a `ConduitM` containing `Data.Void.Void`, but I have `ConduitFlush` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The standard approach to this would be to create some kind of shared variable to communicate between the child thread and the main thread, and have the main thread pop values off of the variable and `send` them with the appropriate functions. My recommendation would be to use [Software Transactional Memory (STM)](https://www.stackage.org/package/stm), and probably something like a [TBQueue](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-6.14/stm-2.4.4.1/Control-Concurrent-STM-TBQueue.html).